# How to have a proper tkinter window with Windows 8?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I already did all the research I could, but can't find an answer.
So my problem is :

**How to make my window take the maximum size WITHOUT the taskbar overlapping with it ?**
I don't want part of my window to be **under the taskbar**.

I tried using the **winfo_screenwidth** and **winfo_screen_height**, but this nor the root.state("zoomed") appear to work : they both resize the window to the screen size, while I want the screen size minus the taskbar.

**Edit** : Seeing how confused my question seems to be :
Let h be the height of my monitor screen in pixel and h_taskbar the height in pixel of the taskbar. How can I make my window take (h - h_taskbar) as height ?( I don't know h_taskbar !)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the fullscreen attribute to True, it is as easy as:

```
root = Tk()
root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
```

However, it doesn't show the title bar. If you want to keep it visible, you can resize the Tk element with the `geometry()`method:

```
root = Tk()
w, h = root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()
root.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (w, h))
```

With `winfo_width()` and `winfo_height()` you can get the width and height or the window, and also you can bind an event handler to the `<Configure>` event:

```
def resize(event):
    print("New size is: {}x{}".format(event.width, event.height))

root.bind("<Configure>", resize)
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this would help you ..

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()

root.geometry("%dx%d" %(screen_width,screen_height))
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `resizable` takes a boolean (True, False) rather than integers. Obviously integers will work since they are truthful, but there's really no point in passing in `screen_width` and `screen_height` to those parameters. Also, `resizable` has absolutely no effect on what the window size _is_, it only prevents or allows you to interactively change it.

Comment: As I said, that's not what I asked. (I already tried this, thank you)